# populating dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have the following code to populate a dropdownlist:

```
string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhoQL"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  using (SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Abrv], [State] FROM [States]", con))
  {
    myda.Fill(ds)
    ddlShipState.DataSource = ds;
  }
}
ddlShipState.DataTextField = "State";
ddlShipState.DataValueField = "Abrv";
ddlShipState.DataBind();
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing it. Notice I didn't have to open and close the connection. Wondering if it makes a difference in my example.
In terms of more efficient I am looking for best code practice for what I have above.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "More efficient" how? You should put the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` into `using` blocks, but other than that what do you mean "more efficient"?

Comment: Define efficient? Lines of code? Speed? Your code is pretty efficient in my humble opinion. But that really depends on what your own demands are. The code could be a bit cleaner obviously, using a `using` statement, but other than that it's fine.

Comment: @Cloud - Thanks for your response. I have it with using now. Let me know if it can improved any more. Thanks

Comment: This should be in code review really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice I didn't have to open and close the connection.

No, but the `DataAdapter` does it implicitely.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx):

> If the IDbConnection is closed before Fill is called, it is opened to
>   retrieve data and then closed. If the connection is open before Fill
>   is called, it remains open.

But also note that opening and closing is not inefficient when you're using [`Connection-Pooling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)(default). Because then `con.Open` just means "wait, i need this connection now" and `con.Close` means "ok, you can reuse it somewhere else now, i'm finished".

So you should always close a connection as soon as you're finished with it. Otherwise the connection-pool needs to open new physical connections everytime which can cause exceptions(maximum default connection count is 100) but always will decrease the performance.

The best way to dispose/close connections(any `IDisposable`) is by using the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhoQL"].ConnectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Abrv], [State] FROM [States]", con))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(tbl);
    ddlShipState.DataSource = tbl;
    ddlShipState.DataTextField = "State";
    ddlShipState.DataValueField = "Abrv";
    ddlShipState.DataBind();
}
```

(sidenote: i've replaced your `DataSet` with a "lighter" `DataTable`)

Comment: Hello Tim, can you help me with the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587474/asp-net-dropdownlist-getting-selectedvalue

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this over and over, you should consider caching the data:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx

That way you'll hit the database just once...even if there are 10,000 users.