# DropdownList getting SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I bind the selected value of the drop down list and assign it to @TimeZone as currently when I select it, @TimeZone is null.

Here is my code:

Within my page load, I have the following code that assigns value to the drop down:

```
ddlTimeZone.DataSource = from p in TimeZoneInfo.GetZones()
                         select new { p.Id };
ddlTimeZone.DataTextField = "Id";
ddlTimeZone.DataValueField = "Id";             
ddlTimeZone.DataBind();
```

Next, within my .aspx file, I have the following:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

.....
.....

```
 InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Companies] ([TimeZone]) VALUES ( @TimeZone)"

 <InsertParameters>                 
        <asp:Parameter Name="TimeZone" Type="String" />           
 </InsertParameters>
```

Again, what I need to know is how do I assign the value of the selected item in the dropdown list to @TimeZone as currently when I select it, @TimeZone it is null.

I tried

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TimeZone") %>' runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

but that gave the following error message:

> 'ddlTimeZone' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not
>   exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned by `<%# Bind("TimeZone") %>` does not exists in the values of the dropdown as you are binding it with the id TimeZoneInfo.GetZones(). Give it some id that exits in data source.

Put this statement in code behind.

```
ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue = "idtthatexists";
```

Edit: Base on assumption that you have TimeZone in data source returned by GetZones()

```
ddlTimeZone.DataSource = from p in TimeZoneInfo.GetZones()
                         select new { p.Id, p.TimeZone };
ddlTimeZone.DataTextField = "Id";
ddlTimeZone.DataValueField = "TimeZone";   
ddlTimeZone.DataBind();
ddlTimeZone.Items.FindByText("SomeTextShowInDropDownItems").Selected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks but how is it going to bind to TimeZone though?

Comment: You need to select the attribute you bind. If you want to select time zone then bind timezone on ddlTimeZone.DataTextField = "timezone"; and use SelectText instead of SelectedValue

Comment: I am sorry Adil, can you do a small example. I am not sure where I woul use the ddlTimeZone.DataTextField , etc.

Comment: Updated my answer, this may help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx

Comment: Hi Adil. Thanks for your answer but what I am looking for is something different. Sorry if I was not clear. When the user selects a value from the dropdown, how do I get it in the @TimeZone as my insert needs "@TimeZone" which I want to tie to the value the user selected from the dropdown. Note that DataTextField and DataValueField is both Id in my case.

Comment: Adil, to make it more clear, when the user selects the value from the dropdown, I like to have that value go into the @TimeZone in  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Companies] ([TimeZone]) VALUES ( @TimeZone)". Please let me know if this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: You can only get the id from dropdownlist as you have id in both datatextfield and datavaluefield. You can use ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue to get the id of timezone. You can use this id to get the time zone for that id, What I suggest to bind TimeZone to dropdown to save a call to database for getting timezone  against id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20187/discussion-between-web-dev-and-adil)